# What is this unused pipe in basement wall

Tags: concrete, basement, pipe, leaking

It is approx a few feet below ground level. It has started leaking/pouring clean water in heavy rain. House built in 1950 on flat level lot. We have owned for almost 2 years and has never leaked before and we live in a rainy area.

The end of the white "tube" is simply resting on the wall and looks like a swivel joint to the pipe. The flashing underneath is to divert water to a bucket. In the heavy rain the bucket needed to be emptied a few times in 24 hours.

There is a gutter drain outside above the area that was knocked off and ground indented from rain water hitting ground directly by the foundation wall. We put  downspout back on and put a board up to also divert outside but still leaks..not as Badly. Appreciate any advice or what trade we should contact to stop the leak.  Unless it is meant to be there to protect the wall from caving in? I read something about that. Thanks very much[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Contact your local caulk gun and wait for a dry day to clean it out and fill the sleeve in between it and that abandoned supply line. Just like they did around the outside of the sleeve with 100% silicone.

Comment: If it doesn't smell acrid or like gasoline, or it says *cleans with water* then it's the wrong kind of caulk. *Cleans with mineral spirits or xylene* is what you want.

Comment: Also, get some bags of dirt and increase the grade next to the house where the gutter is. Keep it a few inches below the sheathing or it'll rot your house and make it so rain can go over the foundation.

Comment: The prev tenant had a dog and did some digging around the area as well. We will def fill in the low area around perimeter , thanks for the tips!